# android dynamic xml

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a `xml` in Android which is

```
 <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="122px"
    android:layout_marginTop="40px"
    android:id="@+id/am"
    android:text="@string/iam"
    android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="20px">
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="40px"
    android:id="@+id/jname"
    android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:id="@+id/going"
android:text="@string/sloc"
android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="20px">
</TextView>
```

My `TextView` `jname` will be dynamic i.e. I will be filling the spot with the data from `JSON`. What I want is that my `TextView` of the `id` `jname` should always come to the right of the `TextView` having source `@string/iam` and left of `TextView` having source `@string/sloc`. I don't want to define `layout_margin` attributes because that would fix the positions and everything will overlap if the width of the dynamic data is not proper. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is purely with layout, then just enclose all of that in a `LinearLayout` and set a weight for the middle `TextView`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="122px"
            android:layout_marginTop="40px"
            android:id="@+id/am"
            android:text="@string/iam"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="20px">
        </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="40px"
        android:id="@+id/jname"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="20px"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/going"
        android:text="@string/sloc"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="20px">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative Layout. Here is an example of Relative Layout http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

Comment: i am using relative layout. Infact i tried toRightOf too but its not working!

Comment: Please can u post full layout xml?